# Can Nginx trace HTTP traffic?

Tags: http, nginx, logging

Does Nginx have HTTP wire logs which when enabled, will log all HTTP requests coming to the server and the responses going out of the server? If so, how do I configure that?

Answer (score 1):

Nginx has access logs as part of `ngx_http_log_module`.

From the documentation at [ngx_http_log_module](http://nginx.org/en/docs/http/ngx_http_log_module.html)

> The ngx_http_log_module module writes request logs in the specified
>   format. Requests are logged in the context of a location where processing
>   ends.

```
log_format compression '$remote_addr - $remote_user [$time_local] '
                       '"$request" $status $bytes_sent '
                       '"$http_referer" "$http_user_agent" "$gzip_ratio"';

access_log /spool/logs/nginx-access.log compression buffer=32k;
```

Comment: I'm not talking about the access log. This only logs the request right? Need to trace both requests and responses.

Comment: You can log things like the response status, bytes sent, arbitrary response header field etc. Take a look at http://nginx.org/en/docs/varindex.html. I don't think you can dump the entire response buffer unless you are willing to modify source code.

Answer (score 0):

To get the request body sent by visitors, use client_body_in_file_only on; and log the "temporary" file it's written to in the logs by appending var $request_body_file to the log format. "Temporary" files will be located in client_temp directory by default.

You can log request headers $http_ too and sent headers with $sent_http_.

Please refer this thread for more details :
https://serverfault.com/questions/636790/nginx-log-complete-request-response-with-all-headers